# Checkbox inside React Accordion does not work in IE Spring Boot Application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, internet-explorer, checkbox, accordion

I am working on Spring Boot application in which I am using React accordion.
I have Checkbox (input type="checkbox") inside title of this accordion. This checkbox works in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge but it does not work in Internet explorer. In IE Accordion click event always takes precedence and checkbox never works.

```
<Accordion>
  {this.state.someSelection.map(iSelection =>
  <AccordionItem
       title={
         <div>
           <MyCheckBox t={t} module={iModule} selected={iSelection.selected} onSelect={this.onSelectSomething}/>
         </div>}
       key={iSelection.name}
     >
       < Some more divs />
       
     </AccordionItem>)
   }
</Accordion>
```

Thanks in advance.
Manmath.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether is it possible to reproduce the issue just using the React accordion or we have to use it with the Spring boot application? I try to make a test with the React Accordion but I am not able to pass the checkbox code inside the title of the Accordion. Please let us know whether there is any simple way to test this issue. It can also help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I am using Spring boot application and typescript file to create GUI pages. The code was already there and needs to make it work with IE. Its using react-light-accordion.